# C# get css property

Tags: c#, html, css

I have an element in c#:

```
HtmlElement element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("idName");
```

The site has an element

```
<ul id="idName" class="className">
```

In the css for this class is registered property of the `background: url ('url')`. How do I know this property from c#?

Comment: is this css being defined in a separate stylesheet?

Comment: yeah, in a separate stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

`System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement.GetAttribute(string)` is what you want IMO.
simply call it passing the **class** and luckily it will return to you the value you're looking for.

Comment: I tried using GetAttribute ("background"), it returns null. GetAttribute ("style") returns "System.__ComObject" string.

Comment: I guess that you must pass either "css" or "class" and what the method returns is a string AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to assign that value to an hidden form field, and then read the field's value in your C# code.

Would be nice to know why you're doing this though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going to have to parse the css file yourself.  When you detect that an element has a class assigned, search the corresponding css file for that class.  Then pull the properties for it and compare.